# How can i prevent reloading the whole page? I don't want to reload the Navbar, only load the components inside using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs

How can i prevent the whole page/Navbar from reloading, i just want to load the components inside without reloading the whole page. I've mentioned both the components below.

App.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom"; 
import Home from './Home';
import ToDoList from './ToDoList';
import Jobs from './Jobs';

const App = () => {


return(
  <>
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
        <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path= '/todolist' element={<ToDoList />}/>
        <Route path= '/jobs' element={<Jobs/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </>
)

}
export default App
```

Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = () => {

    return(
        <nav>
            <ul>
            <a href="/"></a>
            <li>
            <a href="/todolist">ToDoList!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="/jobs">Jobs</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navbar will not rerender with your approach as it's above the router. So only Router component will be rendered for any change.
But issue here is you are using `a` tag which should not be used here as **React** is SPA you need to use `<link to="/url">Text</link>` [Doc](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing)

So in Navbar.js just change your `a` tag to `link` with appropriate props and it will not rerender. Unless Parent component is going to rerender.

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
const Navbar = () => {

    return(
        <nav>
            <ul>
            <link to="/"></link>
            <li>
            <link to="/todolist">ToDoList!</link>
            </li>
            <li>
            <link to="/jobs">Jobs</link>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
export default Navbar
```